# Proof that $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is a compactification of $\mathbb{A}^n.$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I'm learning basic Algebraic Geometry so I would like to make sure my proof arguments are solid before I move on.

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{P}^n$, the complex projective $n$-space, is a compactification of $\mathbb{A}^n$, i.e. there is an embedding with dense image. Considering the lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^{n + 1},$ we can project them onto the hyperplane defined by $x_{n + 1} = 1.$ Hence, we have an embedding of $\mathbb{A}^n$ onto this hyperplane. The remaining lines are the ones that lie parallel to this hyperplane. That is, $x_{n + 1} = 0.$ Now, we can identify $\mathbb{P}^n$ as the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^{2n + 1}.$ Hence, the identification of our embedding on $\mathbb{S}^{2n + 1}$ is $x_{2n}, x_{2n + 1} = 0.$ Since this closure is the entire sphere in the Euclidean topology, and the Euclidean topology is finer than the Zariski topology, we can see that the projective space is a compactification of the affine space in both the Zariski and Euclidean topology.

Does this work?

Comment: There are several issues with your solution. One is notational: You have to decide if $x_k$ denotes real or complex coordinates (you are using both). Second: Even in the Euclidean topology your argument is incomplete, you still have to argue that the projection of the affine space to $CP^n$ is an embedding (density is clear). Lastly: Since every subset of the affine space is Zariski-compact, taking any further compactification in the Zariski topology is quite odd.

Comment: Thank you very much. Isn't it clear that the map is an embedding? The affine space is homeomorphic with the identification of the hyperplane. So we have an embedding into $CP^n$...or is this not as obvious as I think it is. We can form the inverse map by the projection of the first $n$ coordinates from our hyperplane to affine space.
Also, besides notation, was that the only thing wrong? I'm just doing the exercises for myself so I'm not too worried about the presentation. Sorry if it was confusing to read.